# Functions in sql that returns table (Postgres SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these following query that gives me back a table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE EXPL (parent_node, node, filename) AS
     (
      SELECT ROOT.parent_node, ROOT.node, ROOT.filename
      FROM   filesystem   ROOT
      WHERE  ROOT.parent_node = 1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT CHILD.parent_node, CHILD.node, CHILD.filename
      FROM   EXPL PARENT, filesystem CHILD
      WHERE  PARENT.node = CHILD.parent_node
     )

     SELECT   DISTINCT parent_node, node, filename
     FROM     EXPL
     ORDER BY parent_node, node;
END
```

But I want a function that replaces `WHERE  ROOT.parent_node = 1` with `WHERE  ROOT.parent_node = x`. X is an integer that is the functions parameter.

I thought about, but is not correct at all:

```
CREATE FUNCTION childs(x INT) RETURNS TABLE 
RETURN
WITH RECURSIVE EXPL (parent_node, node, filename) AS
     (
      SELECT ROOT.parent_node, ROOT.node, ROOT.filename
      FROM   filesystem   ROOT
      WHERE  ROOT.parent_node = x

      UNION ALL

      SELECT CHILD.parent_node, CHILD.node, CHILD.filename
      FROM   EXPL PARENT, filesystem CHILD
      WHERE  PARENT.node = CHILD.parent_node
     )

     SELECT   DISTINCT parent_node, node, filename
     FROM     EXPL
     ORDER BY parent_node, node;
END;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Not all databases support user defined table functions.

Comment: Ok, i use Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function definition was missing a `BEGIN` & a `QUERY` after `RETURN`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION childs(x int) 
RETURNS TABLE (parent_node integer, node integer, filename varchar(255)) AS
$function$
BEGIN 
RETURN QUERY
WITH RECURSIVE expl (parent_node, node, filename) AS
     (
      SELECT root.parent_node, root.node, root.filename
      FROM   filesystem   root
      WHERE  root.parent_node = x

      UNION ALL

      SELECT child.parent_node, child.node, child.filename
      FROM   expl parent, filesystem child
      WHERE  parent.node = child.parent_node
     )

     SELECT   DISTINCT expl.parent_node, expl.node, expl.filename
     FROM     expl
     ORDER BY parent_node, node;
END 
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Use the function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM childs(1)
```

Comment: Upvoted. Suggestion: you can simplify a bit by changing from language plpgsql to sql, and then removing begin/end, return, etc.

Comment: After calling SELECT * FROM childs(1) I get the error: structure of query does not match function result type. Returned type character varying(255) does not match expected type text in column 3.

Comment: @Marc, can you update the question with some sample data so I can test it.

Comment: @Haleemur Ali just did

Comment: @Marc, the error happened because I guessed the types you were using. see updated answer.